# Spelling Test Grader

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a code that Grades a spelling bee word test, I have my code below. When I type the code it works, but the output just gives me a number, which is good, but how would I change it to a letter grade instead of a number?

```
def how_eligible(essay):
    total = int(0)
    if 'hyperactive' in essay:
        total += int(1)
    if  'chrysanthemum' in essay:
        total += int(1)
    if 'onomatopoeia' in essay:
        total += int(1)
    if 'aardvark' in essay:
        total += int(1)
    if 'magnanimity' in essay:
        total += int(1)
    return total
```

Comment: If you want to return a grade from your function, then I'll suggest you keep a threshold based on 'total'. For example, `if total<=100 and total>=90: return A+`.

Comment: yeah, I guess I could do that, but I was thinking along the lines of not putting numbers in like percent. for example 100% = A, 90=B). I was thinking of if you get all 5 you get an A.   5=A . 4=B . 3= C . 2=D . 1=F . 0=F, something along that line

Comment: You can use a dictionary to map the total to the grades. `mapper = {5: 'A', 4: 'B', 3: 'C', ...}` and then `return mapper[total]`.

Comment: wow, thank you, I didn't think about using that. Thanks, Keyur Potdar